# No Flexbox por que o justify-self não funciona nos filhos de um pai com display:flex?

Tags: html5, css3, flexbox, css

Estou com uma dúvida sobre o `flexbox` e alinhamentos individuais dos filhos.

Gostaria da saber por que o `justify-self` não se funciona quando aplicado no filho de um pai com `flex`, porém o `align-self` funciona normalmente...

Mesmo usando `justify-self: flex-end;` no elemento filho ele não fica alinhado ao final do *container* pai com `flex`

Segue um exemplo prático, veja que o alinhamento horizontal não se aplica, porém o vertical funciona! Por que isso acontece?

**Por que `justify-self` não funciona nos filhos de um pai com `display:flex`?**

```css
html, body {
    display: flex;
}
.container {
    display: flex;
    background-color: silver;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}
.box {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}
.box.x {
    justify-self: flex-end;
}
.box.y {
    align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box x"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="box y"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Segundo a [especificação na W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-align-3/#justify-self-property), a propriedade `justify-self` não se aplica a flexbox:

> **6.1. Inline/Main-Axis Alignment: the justify-self property**
>
> *Applies to:  block-level boxes, absolutely-positioned boxes, and grid items*

E ainda diz no item **6.1.4** da documentação:

> This property does not apply to flex items... (esta propriedade não se aplica a items flex)

E continua:

> ...because there is more than one item in the main axis. (porque há mais de um item no eixo principal)

Na [documentação MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-self):

> *In flexbox layouts, this property is ignored (more about alignment in Flexbox)* (Em layouts flexbox, esta propriedade é ignorada...)

E [nesta outra documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Alignment/Box_Alignment_in_Flexbox) sobre alinhamento em flexbox, diz o seguinte:

> On the main axis Flexbox deals with our content as a group. The amount
>   of space required to lay out the items is calculated, and the leftover
>   space is then available for distribution. The justify-content property
>   controls how that leftover space is used. Set justify-content:
>   flex-end and the extra space is placed before the items,
>   justify-content: space-around and it is placed either side of the item
>   in that dimension, etc.
>
> This means that a justify-self property does not make sense in Flexbox
>   as we are always dealing with moving the entire group of items around.
>
> On the cross axis align-self makes sense as we potentially have
>   additional space in the flex container in that dimension, in which a
>   single item can be moved to the start and end.

Traduzindo (Google):

> No eixo principal, o Flexbox lida com o nosso conteúdo como um grupo.
>   A quantidade de espaço necessária para dispor os itens é calculada e o
>   espaço restante fica disponível para distribuição. A propriedade
>   justify-content controla como esse espaço restante é usado. Ao setar
>   justify-content: flex-end e o espaço extra é colocado antes dos itens,
>   justify-content: espaço ao redor e é colocado em ambos os lados do
>   item nessa dimensão, etc.
>
> Isso significa que uma propriedade justify-self não faz sentido no
>   Flexbox, pois estamos sempre lidando com a movimentação de todo o
>   grupo de itens.
>
> No eixo cruzado auto-alinhamento faz sentido, já que potencialmente
>   temos espaço adicional no contêiner flexível nessa dimensão, no qual
>   um único item pode ser movido para o início e o fim.

No caso do seu exemplo, poderia alinhar o box à direita do contêiner usando `margin-left: auto`:

```css
html, body {
    display: flex;
}
.container {
    display: flex;
    background-color: silver;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}
.box {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}
.box.x {
    /* justify-self: flex-end; */
    margin-left: auto;
}
.box.y {
    align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box x"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="box y"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: É isso ai mesmo Tio, obrigado!

Comment: Muito obrigado, eu ja sabia que dava pra resolver com o "margin-left/margin-right: auto;", mas jamais ia pensar que o justify-self é ignorado, pois era o que faria mais sentido pra mim no momento.