# Centralizar uma única div no body com dsplay: Flex

Tags: css, css3

Tenho o **body** e uma **div** com `width: 320px`;

Gostaria de centralizá-la no **body** que é flex.

Mas veja só, **NÃO** quero centralizar seu conteúdo.

Gostaria de **centralizar** a própria **div** na **body**.

```css
    body {
       display: flex;
    }
       
    div#tudo {
       display: flex;
       width: 320px;
    }
```

```html
<body>

    <div id=tudo>

          <label>teste</label>

    </div>

</body>
```

Uso `margin: 0 auto` ou tem algum recurso **flexbox** para isso?

O que eu busco é por uma propriedade que faça semelhante ao resultado do `align-self: center`. Porém, na **horizontal**.

Comment: Já tentou utilizar o `margin` que cita? Qual foi o resultado? E se não quer usar flex, não fez muito sentido pedir como faz em flex. Aliás, isso deve ter várias duplicadas no site. Chegou a pesquisar?

Comment: Centralizar na horizontal ou vertical?

Comment: Olá Antônio.  Bom dia! Então, com margim dá certo Mas quero passar a usar o flex. Nao fui muito feliz na minha colocação. O que eu busco na verdade é algo semelhante à align-self mas para a horizontal. Acho que não tem né?

Comment: Existe uma GRANDE diferença em um elemento que é um container flex, e o elemento que é filho de um container flex. Te sugiro fortemente que leia esse guia em português sobre flex https://origamid.com/projetos/flexbox-guia-completo/ é meia horinha que vc vai parar para estudar e vai entender melhor o que eu disse e pq sua pergunta é duplicada. Depois que ler o guia leia o link da duplicada, vai te ajudar ;)

Comment: Bom, adicionei informações à pergunta. Se puder ler... Agradeço! Mas vou ler as tuas referências!

Comment: Relacionada ou nova duplicada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/355954/no-flexbox-por-que-o-justify-self-n%c3%a3o-funciona-nos-filhos-de-um-pai-com-display

Answer (score -3):

```
#envolve {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   width: 320px;
}

<body>
<div id="envolve">
<div id=tudo>

      <label>teste</label>

</div>
</div>
</body>
```

tenta isso pra ver se resolve

Comment: Por que isso resolveria o problema?

Comment: Amigão. Não centralizou. Mas, conforme o Antônio disse, parece que o que estou procurando não existe no flex ou  o que estou querendo fazer não é uma boa prática. Obrigado pelo teu tempo. Estou lendo a referência que ele passou!

Comment: Ok amigo, é sempre bom dar uma estudada antes de usar as propriedades...

Comment: mas na realidade o código que você quer é esse mesmo que eu postei, só não funcionou por que eu esqueci de definir a altura e a largura da div "envolve" com a largura máxima da Tela

Comment: Acho que não é "o código que ele quer", ele quer uma explicação de pq e como a coisa funciona... Tente dar uma enriquecida na resposta, acho que vai ajudar mais falar como pesca do que entregar o peixe

Comment: oxe mas se ele quer entender como funciona ele está no Lugar errado, pra entender como funciona o cara vai ver um Tutorial no youtube ou um Tutorial de algum site, ou algum PDF explicando, eu ein

Comment: kkkk, meninos NÃO briguem. Agradeço a todos igualmente, O que aconteceu foi que eu estudei, depois fui para a prática. Como não funcionou da maneira como esperado depois de muiiiiiiiiito quebrar a cabeça resolvi pedir ajuda aqui no fórum. Valeu e obrigado a todos!

Comment: @DemetriusFernandes Talvez tenha entendido errado o propósito do site. O objetivo do Stack Overflow é justamente ser um repositório de conhecimento que utiliza o formato perguntas e respostas, em que, idealmente, a pergunta apresenta um problema e a resposta apresenta uma descrição da solução como propósito de servidor como fonte de pesquisa para a comunidade. Dar um código pronto e dizer para o usuário "se virar sozinho" para entender é exatamente o oposto do que o site propõem. Se quiser, no [meta] já existem várias discussões sobre isso.